# How to Dump jmeter summary report to a file

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter, when I set the file name in the Filename text box, configure the results and run the tests, I see that the file does not have Min, Max, Avg Reponse Times, which are displayed in the summary report.
How can be these values added to report in Jmeter?
Or is there any plug-in which I can use to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe JMeterPluginsCMD  at http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD can save Aggregate reports that contain all the data you see in the UI (like min/max/avg). It only saves in CSV, afaik